# How to use DIP/DP in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been trying for the past hours to find a solution to this problem, but I can't seem to find anything.

I am developing a game for Android using LibGDX. In the emulator, the game looks fine, but when I play it on my phone, everything is different and misplaced. The solution I found for this is using Density Individual Pixels instead of regular pixels, so everything is placed corectly, no matter what device I use. However, I can't seem to find a proper way to do that. The only relevant solution I have found was to use this:

```
   public static float pixelToDP(float dp) {
        return dp * Gdx.graphics.getDensity();
    }
```

I tried resizing some of the objects using the formula above, but they are still different from the emulator.

Please, if anyone has a solution that doesn't involve changing the Ortographic Camera(already tried those), help me!

Comment: I think what you are looking for are viewports: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: No, the problem is not the viewport, but the fact that pixel size differs from device to device

Comment: Yup and that's why you are looking for viewports

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just to add to the what TomGrill said in the comments.

The reason your game looks fine in the emulator is because you have used values that fits the resolution of the emulator.

If you position a sprite at 100,100 on a 1920x1080 resolution, the sprite will be in the upper (or lower, depending on how you orient your y axis) left corner.
On a 200,200 resolution, the sprite will be placed in the middle of the screen.

The size of the sprite is also dependent on the resolution / pixel density. If you have 1 pixel per sq inch, a 32x32 pixel sprite will be 32 inches wide and high. But on a screen with a high pixel density, lets say 100px pr. sq. inch. the 32x32 sprite will look pretty small.

This is where viewports come in. You choose a resolution, lets say 900x540 and you just code for this resolution. The viewport will make sure your game scales up or down to fit any resolution and pixel density. If you place a sprite in the middle of you 900x540 screen, the viewport will make sure that it is placed in the middle of a 1920x1080 resolution.

Even if you wanted to do these calculations yourself, Gdx.graphics.getDensity(); is not of any use on its own. You need the width and the height of the physical screen to find the resolution. And what you would be doing next is reinventing the wheel.